# Django: Filter user records, only show logged in user records

Tags: python, django

I've got a many-to-many table and I have a form which I want users to pick from drop-down menus to facilitate the insert into the junction table.

I want to restrict the records users are shown to their own (only show the records of the user that is logged in). The user variable is the id or pk of the logged in user.

Okay, the code below works now... Solved.

**models.py**

```py
class ActivityEvidence(models.Model):
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    evidence = models.ForeignKey(Evidence, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('activity', 'evidence'),)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.activity}, {self.evidence}'
```

**views.py**

```py
context['form'] = LinkEvidenceForm(user=request.user.id)
```

**forms.py**

```py
class LinkEvidenceForm(forms.Form):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
      # print(user)
      super(LinkEvidenceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.fields['evidence_id'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Evidence.objects.filter(teacher=user).order_by('evidence_name'))
      self.fields['activity_id'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Activity.objects.filter(teacher=user).order_by('activity_name'))
```

Comment: what you can do is maybe make a addition boolean field in abstract user called.. loggedin and set it to true when a user logs in and false when logs out. then u can just query the database like this `users = Teacher.objects.filter(loggedin=True)`

Comment: But maybe more than one is logged in at the same time

Comment: Do u mean you want to show the details only to the person who is logged in? the answer I have given is if you want to show the details of all user currently logged in.

Comment: yeah, just the user that is logged in

Comment: I have posted the answer. you can accept it if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use django's `login_required` decorator for this.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def myview(request):
   pass
```

this will protect your view from being accessed by someone who is not logged in and will redirect them to login page

And as you said , to get the details of currently logged in user you can do that by :

```py
@login_required
def myview(request):
   user = request.user
```

`request.user` will give you the currently logged in user

Comment: name 'request' is not defined. Maybe I need to take a different approach to the whole thing

Comment: You have to use this code in your views.py, where `request` is imported by default